# Javascript insert Object value into another Object with same key

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've a little problem. I create an Object with Date keys, and I've an another Object with a Date, and values. I want get the value of my second Object, and push into my first Object. Thank you for your answers.

My Object (**obj**)

```
2017-05-31 : null
2017-06-01 : null
2017-06-02 : null
2017-06-03 : null
2017-06-04 : null
2017-06-05 : null
2017-06-06 : null
```

My Object with value (**getListDayInbound**)

```
2017-05-31 : // Data
2017-06-03 : // Data
2017-06-06 : // Data
```

My output

```
2017-05-31 : // Data
2017-06-01 : null
2017-06-02 : null
2017-06-03 : // Data
2017-06-04 : null
2017-06-05 : null
2017-06-06 : // Data
```

My code

```
var dateInbound  = '2017-06-03',
    getListDayInbound = response[dateOutbound].solutions[selectedOutbound].inbounds; // Object with values
const obj = {}; // New Object

function addDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
  result = moment(result).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  return result;
}

function removeDays(date, days) {
  var result = new Date(date);
  result.setDate(result.getDate() - days);
  result = moment(result).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
  return result;
}

// Add -/+ 3 days into Key Object
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  obj[removeDays(dateInbound, i)] = null;
  obj[addDays(dateInbound, i)] = null;
}

obj[dateInbound] = null;
```

Comment: What problem are you experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
a = {
  '2017-05-31' : null,
  '2017-06-01' : null,
  '2017-06-02' : null,
  '2017-06-03' : null,
  '2017-06-04' : null,
  '2017-06-05' : null,
  '2017-06-06' : null
};

b = {
  '2017-05-31' : 'someData',
  '2017-06-03' : 'someData',
  '2017-06-06' : 'someData'
};

console.log(Object.assign(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can directly use`Object.assign`, it will replace the values with new values.

check the [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for more details.

Check this snippet:

```js
let obj1 = {a:1, b:2, c:3, d:4}
let obj2 = {b:5, d:10}

obj1 = Object.assign({}, obj1, obj2);

console.log(obj1);
```